# How to group by multiple values in same column in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table for user access to a software application. A user may have multiple accesses with different aspects of the application denoted by alphanumeric ids. Similarly, multiple users may have same or different set of accesses. 
For eg.

```
Table ACCESSTAB
USER             |       USERACCESS                  
-----------------------------------------
Cust1            |       BA1
Cust1            |       BB2
Cust2            |       BA1
Cust2            |       BB2
Cust3            |       CB1
Cust3            |       BA1
```

I would like to group the customers based the same set of accesses. For eg:

```
USER             |       GROUP                  
-----------------------------------------
Cust1            |       Group1
Cust2            |       Group1
Cust3            |       Group2
```

Currently, I have table created for some important users for this purpose as follows:

```
Table USERGROUP
GROUP             |       ACCESS                  
-----------------------------------------
Group1            |       BA1
Group1            |       BB2
Group2            |       CB1
Group2            |       BA1
```

And the below query comparing both tables.

```
select a.USER,u.GROUP from ACCESSTAB a, USERGROUP u where not exists
(select USERACCESS from ACCESSTAB where USER=a.USER order by 1
MINUS
select ACCESS from USERGROUP where GROUP=u.GROUP order by 1)
```

I would like to group the users without using the USERGROUP table as it is difficult to maintain for all users,not to mention addition of accesses would require manual configuration. Performance doesnt matter.

Any advice/assistance is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: hakish way would be to listAgg distinct access order by access then join users on those values and add a window rank to define your groups.  A less hackish way would be to use a full outer join count distinct access for each user and if the count matches boht users then they have the same group and again use dense rank analytic to get you a group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with @jeff6times7 that you should reconsider your data model to make access group-driven, but in the meantime... you could generate a list of access privileges for each user using `listagg()`:

```
select username, listagg(useraccess, ',') within group (order by useraccess) as groupaccess
from accesstab
group by username;

USERNAME GROUPACCESS         
-------- --------------------
Cust1    BA1,BB2             
Cust2    BA1,BB2             
Cust3    BA1,CB1
```

and generate the groups from the distinct aggregates:

```
select 'Group' || rownum as groupname, groupaccess
from (
  select distinct listagg(useraccess, ',') within group (order by useraccess) as groupaccess
  from accesstab
  group by username
  order by groupaccess
);

GROUPNAME GROUPACCESS         
--------- --------------------
Group1    BA1,BB2             
Group2    BA1,CB1
```

and them join them together, e.g. with two CTEs:

```
with user_cte (username, groupaccess) as (
  select username, listagg(useraccess, ',') within group (order by useraccess)
  from accesstab
  group by username
),
group_cte (groupname, groupaccess) as (
  select 'Group' || rownum, groupaccess
  from (
    select distinct listagg(useraccess, ',') within group (order by useraccess) as groupaccess
    from accesstab
    group by username
    order by groupaccess
  )
)
select u.username, g.groupname
from user_cte u
join group_cte g on g.groupaccess = u.groupaccess
order by u.username;

USERNAME GROUPNAME
-------- ---------
Cust1    Group1   
Cust2    Group1   
Cust3    Group2
```

Or you can use the first CTE to build the second so you only hit the actual table once:

```
with user_cte (username, groupaccess) as (
  select username, listagg(useraccess, ',') within group (order by useraccess)
  from accesstab
  group by username
),
group_cte (groupname, groupaccess) as (
  select distinct 'Group' || dense_rank () over (order by groupaccess), groupaccess
  from user_cte
)
select u.username, g.groupname
from user_cte u
join group_cte g on g.groupaccess = u.groupaccess
order by u.username;

USERNAME GROUPNAME
-------- ---------
Cust1    Group1   
Cust2    Group1   
Cust3    Group2
```

or even without the second CTE:

```
with user_cte (username, groupaccess) as (
  select username, listagg(useraccess, ',') within group (order by useraccess)
  from accesstab
  group by username
)
select distinct username,
  'Group' || dense_rank() over (order by groupaccess) as groupname
from user_cte;

USERNAME GROUPNAME
-------- ---------
Cust1    Group1   
Cust2    Group1   
Cust3    Group2
```

(... which is pretty much xQbert's approach)

You can also, if it's useful, include the aggregated `groupaccess` in the output to list the privileges in each group, but that doesn't seem to be required.

Of course, as soon as a user is added (or updated) with a different combination of accesses, a group will be generated (or removed!), and the numbering of existing groups may change - which may be confusing, but not an issue for you. If it is an issue then you're stuck with maintaining your intermediate table.

Comment: I had to check this firsthand just to make sure that the concatenation doesnt go over the max length of column and fortunately it didnt. I wonder how onecould one do it without using listagg. But that's another question for another time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick dirty example:

```
with AccessTab as 
(SELECT '1' muser ,'BA1' useraccess from dual UNION ALL
SELECT '1','BB2' from dual UNION ALL
SELECT '2','BA1' from dual UNION ALL
SELECT '2','BB2' from dual UNION ALL
SELECT '3','CB1' from dual UNION ALL
SELECT '3','BA1' from dual),
cte as (SELECT muser, listagg(userAccess,',') within group (order by useraccess) GRP From AccessTab group by muser)
SELECT A.muser, dense_Rank() over ( order by a.GRP) as mGroup  
FROM cte a
```

Results in:

```
Muser    mGroup
2        1
1        1
3        2
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks your relationships are:

1. a user has one or more privileges
2. a user belongs to one or more groups
3. a group has one or more privileges

It's not perfectly clear about what you mean when you said "difficult to maintain for all users", but it looks like you might be saying the set of user's privileges (#1) and the set of group's privileges (#3) must be equal sets and you're concerned that keeping them consistent with each other would be difficult. If I'm correct in my assumptions, then I would suggest you eliminate rule #1, drop the ACCESSTAB table, and rename the USERGROUP table to GROUP_ACCESS. That will eliminate the update anomaly.

Comment: That would be my preference as well

Comment: But the table cannot be dropped being part of legacy system and dependent on other tables(not sure why it was designed that way). Regarding issue of maintenance, I have more than 25000 users which seems to have variety of access rights with as much as 25 access rights per user and the configuration  to be done manually.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a LISTAGG() function.

```
SELECT USER, LISTAGG(USERACCESS, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY USER) AS USER_ACCESS_GROUP
FROM ACCESSTAB
GROUP BY USER
```

The result will be

```
USERNAME| USER_ACCESS_GROUP
Cust1     BA1, BB2             
Cust2     BA1, BB2             
Cust3     BA1, CB1
```

If you have a special name for each of these groups, you can wrap the LISTAGG() in a DECODE() function.